# Ethernet device disappears

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

A short time after login, my ethernet port disappears from the output of `ip addr` and other network commands.

Here is what `journalctl` has to say about it:

```
okt 18 14:34:12 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632452.6250] agent-manager: agent[0f88c78839afea0c,:1.102/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
okt 18 14:34:40 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632480.2391] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enx4865ee1f4184) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632624.0299] device (enx4865ee1f4184): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632624.0535] dhcp4 (enx4865ee1f4184): canceled DHCP transaction
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632624.0536] dhcp4 (enx4865ee1f4184): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632624.0536] dhcp4 (enx4865ee1f4184): state changed no lease
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <info>  [1697632624.0544] policy: set 'LumenRadio' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
okt 18 14:37:04 taket NetworkManager[1602]: <warn>  [1697632624.0937] dns-sd-resolved[1a8f89cc3acda0cd]: send-updates SetLinkDomains@5 failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 5 not known
```

In the file `/run/NetworkManager/device/5` (looking at 5 since it seems to be the index at which eth0 briefly was, see above), I have this:

```
[device]
managed=true
```

I have run `nm-applet` for ever, it has never been an issue. I tried to disable it (not start it at boot) since it is in the journal above and reboot, it didn't help.

Edit: it seems that ethernet disappears when I start Chrome.

This is in the output of `sudo lshw -C network` after boot, but disappears after starting Chrome (or just some random time after login):

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 11
       bus info: usb@2:3.2.4
       logical name: enx4865ee1f4184
       serial: 48:65:ee:1f:41:84
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=46.195.233.27 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

Why does the ethernet device seem to disappear? I suppose that `(enx4865ee1f4184): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')` is the culprit, but how do I investigate further?